# How to set Title in center of Toolbar in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How can i set Title in center of toolbar in fragment.

I have tried various way but They didn't work.
I want to set Tittle in center with bold style.

[image]

[image]

i want to set these tittles in center with bold style

Comment: you shouldn't use layout_constraintVertical_bias for this case, but use contraints between views items. About your problem, this is not clear what you want ? There is no tabbar here ? Or which view id do you want to center ?

Comment: Share your toolbar layout inside the fragment.

Comment: how to share toolbar layout inside fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `text view` inside `toolbar` like this :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

and if you want to set the `text view` text to your app title use this :

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title) ;
t.setText(getTitle()) ;
```

---

The result :

[image]

Comment: not working in my case. after applying your code. It shows two Tittles

Comment: @Buddy because you must remove the original title , like using `setTitle("") ;` or another way if you are using toolbar instead of action bar .